# Getting "Maximum call stack size exceeded error" using protractor

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver, protractor, callstack

Im getting **"Maximum call stack size exceeded error"** intermittently.

I saw few posts where it says possible reason would be due to **recursion**

I have 3 files

```
1) conf.js
2) mainSpec.js
3) page1.js
```

Calling "mainSpec.js" from "conf.js"

```
suites: {
         spec1 : '../specs/mainSpec.js'
    },
 global.URL = 'http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/';
```

"mainSpec.js"

```
page1= require('../pages/page1.js');
    describe('samplespec', function () {

        beforeEach(function () {
             browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
            console.log('+++++++++Before Each++++++++');
        });
        afterEach(function () {
            console.log('+++++++++After Each++++++++');
        });

        it('mysampcode', function () {
            //Login 
            page1.getLoginPage(URL);
            .
            .
            .
     });
    });
```

"Page1.js"

```
  module.exports = {

        getLoginPage: function (appurl) {
            browser.get(appurl);
            browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        },
    };
```

When i execute p**roctractor conf.js** from **cmd prompt**
i get below error.

[image]

Mostly it will launch the url and continues the execution, but few times it is throwing **"Maximum call stack size exceeded error"**, im unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: This error can occur by the exports object too. Can you convert Page1.js into a function and then export that function to see if you get same error? Thanks